# My ExoPlayer is keeps on buffering even with good data connectivity

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using ExoPlayer to play videos from URL. For some reason, my video keeps on buffering even it is low size video also. Please find the code snippet below which I have used to build ExoPlayer.

```
private MediaSource buildMediaStore(String mediaUrl) {
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(mediaUrl);
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, getApplicationInfo().packageName), defaultBandwidthMeter);
    DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

    return new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorFactory, null, null);
}




    defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(defaultBandwidthMeter);
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(ViewVideoNewPotriateFullScreen.this),
            new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory), new DefaultLoadControl());
    MediaSource datasource = buildMediaStore(url);
    exoPlayer.prepare(datasource, true, true);
    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
    simpleExoPlayer.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
    exoPlayer.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_OFF);
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    exoPlayer.seekTo(getIntent().getLongExtra("position", 0));

    //updateTimers();
    exoPlayer.addListener(this);
```

Comment: Got the same problem here.
HlsMediaSource is buffering and streaming fine, while ExtractorMediaSource keeps buffering to 100%...